# BCP Imported File in UTF-8 Encoded File

Tags: sql, sql-server, encoding, utf-8, bcp

I have generated a CSV file using BULK Copy (BCP) utility in SQL Server 2008. I want a file that will be in UTF-8 Encoding. I am using below code to generate File. Any one can help me to resolve this problem.

```
DECLARE @Path VARCHAR(100) ,
@sql VARCHAR(8000) ,
@DBName VARCHAR(100) ,
@exePath VARCHAR(100),

SELECT @sql = 'bcp "SELECT * FROM '+@DBName+'..ABC" queryout  '+@Path+'\'+'ABC'.csv -c -k     -t, -U sa -P abc -T -S ' + @@servername
```

exec @exePath @sql;

Answer (score 2):

Sql Server 2008 don't support utf-8 but you can use "-w" instead "-c"  that will use UTF-16 as mentionned by DiMach, the probleme is  that the csv file not will be well formed.

If you trying to export csv file for specific language, for example french (french contains spécial caracters : à é â ç ...) you will need to know that there is an other solution :

- **First** : try to search in the internet the encoding that support all charaters of the target language, for example for french we can found ISO-8859-1
- **Second** : search in the internet a page code related to encoding that you find, for      ISO-8859-1 is 1252
- **Third** : execute to following sql request in your sql server to see if your sql server support this encoding

  select name, COLLATIONPROPERTY(name, 'CodePage') as Code_Page, description
  from sys.fn_HelpCollations() where COLLATIONPROPERTY(name, 'CodePage')=1252 order by Code_Page
- **fourth** : in BCP command use -C 1252 only (delete -c and -w)

I hope that's help

Comment: What version of sql supports utf 8 for bcp, is it 2014 onwards? I am on 2012

Answer (score 0):

Just replace "-c" parameter with "-w"

```
SELECT @sql = 'bcp "SELECT * FROM '+@DBName+'..ABC" queryout  '+@Path+'\'+'ABC'.csv -w -k     -t, -U sa -P abc -T -S ' + @@servername
```

Comment: **"-w"** flag forces bcp to export in Unicode, which in MS SQL is UTF-16, not UTF-8.